# Reduce array to anonymous hash code

Tags: perl

Is there anyway to do something like this in perl (convert array hash and use it in one line)?

```
sub func{
 #from this
 my %args = @_;
 print $args{test};

 #to this
 print %{@_}{test};
}
```

Im using it for passing errors to callbacks like javascript
    use strict;
    use warnings;

```
sub error{
 my $msg = shift;
 print("ERROR: $msg\n");
}

sub parse_args{
    my %args = @_;
    return $args{args};
}

sub do_something{
   my $args = parse_args(
     args=>{@_},
     optional_args=>["fail_cb"]
   );
   if(!0){
    return(exists $args->{fail_cb} ? $args->{fail_cb}->(err=>"not good") : 0);
   }
}

do_something(
 fail_cb => sub{error(({@_})->{err});}
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by making it into a reference and then dereferencing

```
sub func { say ${{@_}}{key} }
```

(I must ask, do you really want to be doing this?)

The `{@_}` creates a hash reference, while `${ ... }{}` syntax [dereferences it (item 2)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Using-References).

---

**Update to the question edit**

Apparently, the intent is to run a callback. But then you need to *run* that callback

```
sub func { ${{@_}}{key}->() }

func( key => sub { say "cb here" } );
```

If you were to print the value, as asked, you'd get the code-reference itself, `CODE(0x...)`

Or, pass the hashref with a key and (the reference of) arguments for the callback

```
my $hr = { k1 => sub { .. }, k2 => sub { .. }, .. };
...
func($hr, $key, $arrayref_cb_args);

sub func { $_[0]->{$_[1]}->(@{$_[2]}) }
```

where now `func` can decide dynamically what to run. This gives you far more flexibility in design.

For a ready test

```
perl -wE'
    sub tt { $_[0]->{$_[1]}->(@{$_[2]}) };
    tt( { k1 => sub { say "args: @_" }}, "k1", [qw(cb here)] )
'
```

prints the line   `args: cb here`

Comment: Im using like javascript passes errors to callbacks. I will update question to explain.

Comment: the main part that I think is ugly is encapsulating the callback within an anonymouse subroutine but from what I can tell, I can't pass a subroutine reference with parameters as the callback ( fail_cb =>\&error(({@_})->{err}) 
 ). This idea is that I can have a subroutine success(),exit(), etc.. that will display the message differently or I can define a completely new one as an anonymose subroutine and still have the err functionality.

Comment: The callback is still called within the do_something function in this case and the above code seems to work correctly as far as I can tell.

Comment: I think I understand the code (barely) but I am not sure how to apply it to what I'm trying to do. Would the subs defined in $_[0] be error, success, etc..? Also would it make more sense to define $_[0] hash outside tt so that it can be reused with multiple tt calls?

Comment: @TheAschr For example, if you have `$rh = { error => sub { say "got error: @_" } }`, then yes, `func($hr, "error", $cb_args)` will run `sub { say "...: @_" }` with whatever is in arrayref `$cb_args`. You can have a default for `$cb_args` refarray so that it's optional.

Comment: @TheAschr As for the rest of your comment -- yes, this is what I show in the edit and one-liner; the hashref (`$_[0]` in the sub) is built somewhere else, so `func(...)` can dynamically select which one to run and how (with what arguments). All this is only a sketch; what is shown can easily be done otherwise but I assume that you have more elaborate needs, passing these things further etc.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help! This was super helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn it into a hash *reference* easily with just

```
{@a}
```

and dereference entries with, for example

```
({@a})->{key}
```

Here's a debugger log:

```
$ perl -de0

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.49_001
Editor support available.

Enter h or 'h h' for help, or 'man perldebug' for more help.

main::(-e:1):   0
  DB<1> @a = ('a',1,'b',2,'c',3)

  DB<2> x @a
0  'a'
1  1
2  'b'
3  2
4  'c'
5  3
  DB<3> x {@a}
0  'a'
1  1
2  'b'
3  2
4  'c'
5  3
  DB<4> x ({@a})
0  HASH(0x804d82e0)
   'a' => 1
   'b' => 2
   'c' => 3
  DB<5> x ({@a})->{c}
0  3
```

Comment: The parens are not needed